# What is the worst case time complexity of median of medians quicksort?

Tags: time-complexity, quicksort, quickselect, median-of-medians

What is the worst case time complexity of median of medians quicksort ( pivot is determined by the median of medians which take O(n) time to find )?

Comment: If I remember my algorithms correctly, I think it's `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Why ? Median of medians ensures good partitions in each case .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians),

> The approximate median-selection algorithm can also be used as a pivot strategy in quicksort, yielding an optimal algorithm, with worst-case complexity O(n log n).

This is because the median of medians algorithm prevents the bad partitioning that would occur in naive quicksort on an already sorted array.